# Black screen on VirtualBox startup emulation

Tags: sd-card, virtualization

I have a raspberry pi 2, with a raspbian-stretch (2017-09-07) operative system burn into sd-card by using etcher-1.1.2 app. Raspberry works well!. I tryed follow many guides for mount sd-card operating system in Vrtual-Box(5.1.30) linux application, but at startup a black screen appears. I follow these steps:

- umount sd card (Device /dev/mmcblk0)
  (/dev/mmcblk0p1 FAT32 boot partition, /dev/mmcblk0p2 Ext4 data partition)
- use VirtualBox command:
  sudo VBoxManage internalcommands createrawvmdk -filename /home/user/Desktop/raw_file/file.vmdk -rawdisk /dev/mmcblk0
  and appear:
  RAW host disk access VMDK file /home/user/Desktop/raw_file/file.vmdk created successfully.
- start Virtual-box in root mode
- create a new machine without hdd and operative system
- add SATA controller and select file.vmdk
  I tried to mount and remount sd partition but nothing changed!
  Please, help me, thanks in advance.
  [image: sdcard configuration]

Comment: AFAIK virtualbox does not support ARM OS's.

Answer (score 2):

You can't run an ARM Raspbian image on an x86 system. If you want to run the Raspbian Pixel Desktop you can download the x86 iso at [raspberrypi.org](https://www.raspberrypi.org/downloads/raspberry-pi-desktop/)

Comment: Thank Steve Robillard and 88weighed for your answers, my original intent was modify the /dev file of raspberry pi, by using emulation. But seem that it can't be done! Thanks a lot.

Comment: @init0 have you tried a live linux dvd